# Why MyFragment is loaded by PathClassLoader not MyClassLoader

Tags: android, classloader, patch

we are using custom `MyClassLoader` extends `ClassLoader` to replace default `PathClassLoader`, like:

```
    Context mBase = (Context) getFieldValue(application, "mBase");
    Object mPackageInfo = getFieldValue(mBase, "mPackageInfo");
    ORIGINAL_CLASS_LOADER = (ClassLoader) getFieldValue(mPackageInfo, "mClassLoader");
    CUSTOMED_CLASS_LOADER = new MyClassLoader(ORIGINAL_CLASS_LOADER);
```

executed when application is onCreat.

The first problem is, Not all classes is loaded first by  `MyClassLoader`, just `MyActivitys` and `MyViews` are loaded by `MyClassLoader`, `MyFragments` are still loaded by `PathClassLoader`. Does this have something todo with Context?

In `MyClassLoader` we load class by

```
    public Class<?> loadClass(String className)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            ClassLoader myDexClassLoader = loaders.get("DEX");
            if(myDexClassLoader != null){
                Class<?> c = null;
                try {
                     c = myDexClassLoader.loadClass(className);
                    // c = loader.findClass(className);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                }
                if (c != null) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
        } 
        return super.loadClass(className);
    }`
```

and *myDexClassLoader* is defined as

```
    public static class MyDexClassLoader extends DexClassLoader {

    public MyDexClassLoader(String dexPath, String dexOutputDir,
            String libPath, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(dexPath, dexOutputDir, libPath, parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.findClass(name);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String className)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        try {
            clazz = findClass(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        if (clazz != null) {
            return clazz;
        }
        return super.loadClass(className);
    }

}
```

`MyDexClassLoader` is inited with PatchDex file contains classes like *A1* and *C1*.

`PathClassLoader` is both `MyDexClassLoader` and `MyClassLoader` 's parent.

And in OriginalApk we have the original class *A1* *B1* *C1*.

The second problems is, we can print in the `loadClass` method, that **new A1**  is loaded from PatchDex by `MyDexClassLoader` (called by `MyClassLoader`),

but as class *B1* is not in the PatchDex, `MyDexClassLoader`  ( why not first called by `MyClassLoader` ) finally use it's parent(`PathClassLoader`) to load the **old B1**,

class B1 is using C1 directly, so we have to load class C1. By print loadClass method we found  `MyDexClassLoader` has taken control, but not using it's PatchDex, just using parent's `PathClassLoader`'s **old C1**.

How does this happen? Why `MyDexClassLoader` load class C1 directly by it's parent, but not it's PatchDex when it has ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forget there is another problem, why `MyClassLoader` is not allway the first called classloader? Sometimes `MyDexClassLoader`'s `loadClass`  is directly called without calling  `MyClassLoader` 's `loadClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the classloaders in andorid for dex is different from java's classloader.

for example, pathclassloader and dexclassloader doesn't reference child anymore. these classloader has its own dex file lists for load class from dex files that registered.

so, do not use super class first. 
must find class from your own custom class loader first.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are saving my day!  I double checked source code, it's  `private final DexPathList pathList;` in  BaseDexClassLoader , so all find is finding itself's DexPathList pathList.